# Express routing with query String

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

i am currently trying node & express. The Project is a small Movie Library. Today i tryed to implement a search for titles of movies, the problem i have is when i submit my form and get my query String like this http://localhost:3000/movies/?title=Hustlers i get all the Data in my Database. But when i manually type the Url like this http://localhost:3000/movies/title=Hustlers it works fine and i get the matching result. I tryed change my Routes but i am stuck right now.

here is the movies.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const Movie = require("../models/movie");

//Get Back all the movies
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const movies = await Movie.find();
    res.json(movies);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});

//specific Movie
router.get("/title=:title", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const movie = await Movie.find({ title: req.params.title });
    res.json(movie);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

my app.js

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");
require("dotenv/config");

//Middlewares
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded());


const moviesRoute = require("./routes/movies");
app.use("/movies", moviesRoute);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/"));

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/testDB", { useNewUrlParser: true });
app.listen(3000);
```

and my submit form here

```
 <form action="/movies/">
       <input type="text" name="title" />
         <input
          type="submit"
          value="Suchen"
          class="btn btn-primary btnNewMovie"
        />
  </form>
```

Comment: The '?' in your first localhost address makes `title` a query parameter, not a route parameter.
To get the query param in eg. `http://localhost:3000/movies?title=Hustlers`, use `req.query.title` rather than `req.params.title`.

Comment: I changed it like you said but i still get all the movies instead of just the one that im searching for.

Answer (score 0):

The `=` is messing it up, because that character is reserved for the query component. It would also look much cleaner as `/title/movie_title`. Try this:

```
router.get("/title/:title", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const movie = await Movie.find({ title: req.params.title });
    res.json(movie);
  } catch (err) {
    res.json({ message: err });
  }
});
```

Comment: I tryed your solutions but it still doesnt work. Still getting all movies instead of just the one im searching for.

Comment: if you console.log(req.params.title) what do you get?

Comment: Strange, i cant console.log inside of the Routing functions.

Answer (score 0):

There's a difference between query string params and route params.

When you submit a form, normally it will encode the request as application/x-www-form-urlencoded ([More info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST)), then the express router parse those values and provide them thru the query hash. For more information on how to properly use the route params on express go [here](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) and read the **Route parameters** section.